# Появление блока при наведении на другой блок javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Нашел на просторах интернета данный код

```
<html>

  <head>
    <style>

      .hover {
        display: none;
      }

    </style>
  </head>

  <body>

    <div id="w1">
      <div id="block">Сюда надо навести</div>
    </div>
    <div id="w2">
      <div rel="block" class="hover">Текст появится</div>
    </div>

    <script>
      var bl = document.getElementById('block'),
        hv = document.querySelector('.hover');

      bl.onmouseover = function () {
        hv.style.display = 'block';
      }

      hv.onmouseout = function () {
        hv.style.display = 'none';
      }
    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Почему при переименовании элемента 'block' код перестает работать? Хочу сделать, чтобы на одной странице  было 3 элемента при наведении на которые должны появляться разные сообщения.

http://jsfiddle.net/3pgbdq6m/ - не работает уже

Comment: Всё работает. Если вы тестируете не на компьютере, то работать не будет, т.к здесь действие выполняется при наведении именно курсора мышки. Используйте focus и focusout для того, чтобы это работало на всех устройствах

Comment: Обновил ссылку, мне надо сделать 3 разных элемента при наведении на которые должны появляться разные сообщения. Если просто переименовывать, то работать не будет.

Comment: Если JQuery интересует, то могу написать.

Comment: добавил ответ посмотрите

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$('div.container-focus').mouseover(function() {
  $('.container').find('p').each(function() {
    $(this).css('display', 'none');
  });

  var focus = $(this).attr('data-focus');

  $('.'+focus).css('display', 'block');
});
```

```css
p {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="container-focus" data-focus="focus-1">
    Тут наводим 1
  </div>
  <p class="focus-1">Это показываем 1</p>

  <div class="container-focus" data-focus="focus-2">
    Тут наводим 2
  </div>
  <p class="focus-2">Это показываем 2</p>

  <div class="container-focus" data-focus="focus-3">
    Тут наводим 3
  </div>
  <p class="focus-3">Это показываем 3</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Евгений создайте блок с нужным текстом. И при наведении показывайте его в нужном месте. Даже если текст в другом блоке, практически у любого объекта HTML есть свойство innerHTML которое позволит вам достать содержимое.

Comment: Можно пример, пожалуйста?

Comment: @Евгений исправил, теперь элемент с текстом может находиться в любом месте